golang testcontainers withTmpFs
I'm looking for the testcontainers .withTmpFs equivalent for Golang. I've tried:
pgContainer, err := postgres.Run(ctx, "postgres:15.3-alpine",
    testcontainers.WithEnv(env),
    testcontainers.WithHostConfigModifier(func(hc *container.HostConfig) {
        hc.CgroupnsMode = "host"
        hc.Tmpfs = map[string]string{
            "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": "rw",
        }
        hc.Mounts = []mount.Mount{}
    }),
    postgres.WithInitScripts(filepath.Join("..", "testdata", "init-db.sql")),
    testcontainers.WithWaitStrategy(
        wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
            WithOccurrence(2).WithStartupTimeout(5*time.Second)),
)

however, this results in not loading the initScripts in that directory. It looks like this was asked before but it seems archived. Any ideas?

In which way is it supposed to increase the speed of your unit tests? The startup time of PostgreSQL by far exceeds to time required for provisioning the FS, and unless you are load testing (which would not make much sense in a unit test), the difference in processing speed is negligible, given how PostgreSQL works. So, what are you trying to achieve here?

@MarkusWMahlberg thanks for your comment. There is no mention about speeding up unit tests anywhere. That is not my goal. I'm using testcontainers through KubeDock on k8s where the user running the pod is not allowed to access certain directories on the image. I w'ld to mount a tmpFs on those directories to let me access them.

Which is supposed to solve what problem exactly?

Take the following code:
package postgres_test

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "database/sql"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/ioutils"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/modules/postgres"
    "github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/wait"
)

func PostgresPerformance(b *testing.B, additionalOption ...testcontainers.ContainerCustomizer) {
    b.StopTimer()

    ctx := context.Background()

    dbName := "users"
    dbUser := "user"
    dbPassword := "password"

    opts := []testcontainers.ContainerCustomizer{
        postgres.WithDatabase(dbName),
        postgres.WithUsername(dbUser),
        postgres.WithPassword(dbPassword),
        postgres.WithInitScripts("./_testdata/create_users.sql"),
        testcontainers.WithHostConfigModifier(func(hostConfig *container.HostConfig) {

            hostConfig.AutoRemove = true
            hostConfig.Tmpfs = map[string]string{"/var/lib/postgresql/data": "rw"}

        }),
        testcontainers.WithWaitStrategy(
            wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections").
                WithOccurrence(2).
                WithStartupTimeout(5 * time.Second)),
    }
    opts = append(opts, additionalOption...)
    postgresContainer, err := postgres.Run(ctx,
        "docker.io/postgres:16-alpine",
        opts...,
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start container: %s", err)
    }
    // Clean up the container
    defer func() {
        if err := postgresContainer.Terminate(ctx); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to terminate container: %s", err)
        }
    }()

    b.ResetTimer()
    b.StartTimer()
    s, err := postgresContainer.ConnectionString(context.Background(), "sslmode=disable")

    assert.NoError(b, err)
    require.NotEmpty(b, s)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", s)
    require.NoError(b, err)
    require.NotEmpty(b, db)
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO users (id,name) VALUES ($1,'test')")
    require.NoError(b, err)
    require.NotEmpty(b, stmt)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _, err = stmt.Exec(i)
        assert.NoError(b, err)
    }
}

func BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs(b *testing.B) {
    testcontainers.Logger = log.New(&ioutils.NopWriter{}, "", 0)
    PostgresPerformance(b, testcontainers.WithHostConfigModifier(func(hostConfig *container.HostConfig) {
        hostConfig.Tmpfs = map[string]string{"/var/lib/postgresql/data": "rw"}
    }))
}

func BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs(b *testing.B) {
    testcontainers.Logger = log.New(&ioutils.NopWriter{}, "", 0)
    PostgresPerformance(b)
}

Now, that being said, I fear we have a case of premature optimization. Benchmarking against a test setup does not make sense, so the only way this setup would substantially speed up the unit test is when you have a metrics f..ton of operations in a single unit test, and I would question what is to be tested there.
The actual benchmarks I got looked like this:
$ go test -cpu 1,2,4,6,8,10 -run ^$ -bench .
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: github.com/dacoso-devops/darktrace-closer/postgres
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs                 3861            271425 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs-2               4474            262058 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs-4               4732            253408 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs-6               4902            257025 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs-8               4719            250792 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithTempfs-10              3769            274769 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs              4723            253735 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs-2            4459            603769 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs-4            4597            279881 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs-6            3991            262567 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs-8            4174            275735 ns/op
BenchmarkPostgresWithoutTempfs-10           4232            267782 ns/op
PASS
ok      github.com/dacoso-devops/darktrace-closer/postgres      98.542s

It should be obvious that using tempfs plays a rather insignificant role when it comes to performance.

Nice for this comment. It focusses on the benchmark. Not specifically on the mounting of temporary filesystems. To focus on that original question, am I corect that the testcontainers. WithHostConfigModifier is the withTmpFs equivalent?
